# CropPickerController and CropPickerView giving error when compiling Swift project

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoapods

Using the Pod install, i integrated this framework into my project, but due to the simple fact of installing the pod, it already has these errors, Has anyone been there?

Edit: I have already integrated the OpenCV Pod into the project and it is working normally!

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437837/xcode10-dyld-library-not-loaded-for-pod-installed-in-framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode10 - dyld: Library not loaded for pod installed in framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437837/xcode10-dyld-library-not-loaded-for-pod-installed-in-framework)

Comment: I have Pod OpenCV integrate on this project. But when I integrate it CropPickerController, it fails!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that appears in a project that is being used Pod OpenCV, right after the pod install of CropPickerController no longer runs the application, just for the simple fact of including a new pod.

[image: error project]